# How to preview functions and defines in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to preview all functions and definitions in a file using VSCode?

I'm using Xcode before. and in Xcode you can click the navigator in the top, and it will show you all the functions and definitions in one file. so you can location to your function quickly.

I have read the VScode document , and I didn't find this feature like Xcode. So I want to know is there a way to implement that function like Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the outline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_outline-view) built into vscode.  With it you can easily see a list of all your functions and other symbols in a file.

> The Outline view is out of preview and now enabled by default. It is a separate section in the bottom of the File Explorer. When expanded, it will show the symbol tree of the currently active editor.

[image: outline demo]

> There are several Outline view settings which allow you to
>   enable/disable icons and control the errors and warnings display (all
>   enabled by default):

```
outline.icons - Toggle rendering outline elements with icons.
outline.problems.enabled - Show errors and warnings on outline elements.
outline.problems.badges - Toggle using badges for errors and warnings.
outline.problems.colors - Toggle using colors for errors and warnings.
```